# Avoid figures encroaching on page numbers with LyX

Tags: graphics, lyx, wrapfigure, dimensions

I'm using LyX and have figures in floats and wraps but some of them are too high on the page when converted to PDF and overlap with page numbers.  Is there a way to avoid this and respect the text margins that are set?

Answer (score 1):

Set the width and/or height of the image inside the fugure menu. Mouse over the image, then right click.

Comment: I guess i'll have to play with it because now it moved everything so that the image is by itself on the page even after gong back to the settings I had. :( But thanks! I thought the bounding box would crop it.